# How can I detect the existence of an account in azure Graph SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the graph API in azure functions.
User information is obtained from B2C using objectId.
If you request the objectID of an existing user, I will get the correct user information.
On the other hand, if a non-existent user's objectID is requested, a 500 error occurs.
What I would like to do in this situation is to request the objectID to see if the user exists.
If it exists, user information is returned, but if it does not exist, it cannot be detected because nothing is returned with a 500 error.
Is there any good way to do this?

```
var client = new GraphServiceClient(new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication));

var user = await client.Users
    .Request
    .Filter($"id eq '{objectId}'")
    .GetAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Should I change the inside of the filter property?
Can someone please help me?

Comment: You could use `try catch` block and within `catch` can write something  like  `catch (ServiceException ex) { return this.StatusCode(ex.StatusCode); }` because `Microsoft Graph` has [`ServiceException`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/9c89457f9215a691396f44fd85ef7e89e93f91d5/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Exceptions/ServiceException.cs) class to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[MdFaridUddinKiron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9663070/md-farid-uddin-kiron)  for your valuable suggestion to detect the existence of an account in Azure Graph SDK.

> You could use  `try catch`  block and within  `catch`  can write something like

```
catch (ServiceException ex) 
{ 
return this.StatusCode(ex.StatusCode);
}
```

> because  `Microsoft Graph`  has  [`ServiceException`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/9c89457f9215a691396f44fd85ef7e89e93f91d5/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Exceptions/ServiceException.cs)  class to handle this.